# Setting float format in Struts2 for entire application

Tags: struts2

I'm using Struts2 to develop an application that needs to **display** all floats with the following format: "#.00", meaning the integer part, a point as the decimal separator and the first two digit of the decimal part.

Is there a way (maybe using the global.properties file) to set this behaviour for the application?

Answer (score 0):

i think what you should do is to implement [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) or [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and place your float format in the session or context. You can then use ognl or struts 2 property tags to access them in your jsp.